# ClassNotFoundException when using a self-created jar file

Tags: java, jar, classloader, classnotfoundexception

Using Eclipse I created some parser classes I want to provide to another project as a jar archive for validation purposes. So the parser project look like this:

```
ParserProject
- src
-- com.package.x
--- ClassA
--- ClassB
- lib
-- external1.jar
-- external2.jar
```

The `ClassA` and `ClassB` use the external jar archives, like Jackson or some Apache commons. To provide the functionality to another project, I exported the entire project as jar archive  and executable jar archive (**Right click on project > Export... > Java > JAR file > Select all files and "Export generated class files and resources" > Finish**).

The jar file is created without any errors. When I use the `parserproject.jar` in my validation project, I can access all my methods using auto completion, but when I run the validation project, I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException`.

Now three strange things:

1. All jackson jars are included in the parser project. Besides, I can run a `main()` method in the parser project and everything works fine, no `ClassNotFoundException` occurs.
2. When I add the `parserproject.jar` to my validation project in the class path and open the jar archive in the Package Explorer, the parserproject.jar seems to contain all jars it needs.
3. For the executable jar archive, all required external jars are contained in the `MANIFEST.MF` (**Package Explorer > validation project > Referenced Libraries > + besides parserproject.jar > META-INF > MANIFEST.MF**). It looks like this:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>       Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ json-20140107.jar jackson-annotations-2.5.4.jar ja
>        ckson-core-2.5.4.jar jackson-databind-2.5.4.jar commons-io-2.4.jar co
>        mmons-validator-1.3.1.jar slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
>         json-schema-validator-2.2.6.jar jackson-module-jsonSchema-2.4.4.jar 
>        juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar snakeyaml-1.15.jar commons-beanutils-1.7.
>        0.jar commons-digester-1.6.jar commons-logging-1.0.4.jar joda-time-2.
>        8.1.jar jopt-simple-4.6.jar jsr305-3.0.0.jar json-schema-core-1.2.5.j
>        ar libphonenumber-6.2.jar jackson-coreutils-1.8.jar commons-lang-2.6.
>        jar guava-16.0.1.jar msg-simple-1.1.jar btf-1.2.jar mailapi-1.4.3.jar
>         uri-template-0.9.jar
>       Class-Path: .
>       Rsrc-Main-Class: com.package.SchemeValidator
>       Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader

4. I get the exception if and only if I use the generated jar file in my validation project. In case I get rid of the `parserproject.jar` and define a dependency to the ecplise parser project instead (**Right click on validation project > Properties > Java Build Path > Projects**) I do not get the `ClassNotFoundException`.

So now my question is, how I should export the jar so that every class is found. Thank you!

Comment: The external jar files are not added to the jar when it is created from Eclipse. Can you not provide the external libraries along with your parser jar to the validation project?

Comment: Sadly, I don't have eclipse right now to test. But if I remember correctly, there is an option "bundle dependencies" in the .jar exportation menu. You could use that, or else, you will have to add the dependencies to the MANIFEST file inside the .jar.  You could also execute the .jar without the -jar option and define your own classpath, if you know the main-class you want to use. Many options :)

Comment: Hi @Sekkuar thank you for your answer. They are mentioned in the manifest file but the exception still appears.

Comment: Your classpath in the manifest is "./<dependency>". This means all dependencies must be in the same directory you are executing your .jar from. Are they there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider creating a so called fat jar which will contain all the needed classes. For example: http://fjep.sourceforge.net/

If you do not want to go through the hassle of managing all the depencencies by yourself, consider using a build tool like
Maven https://maven.apache.org/ or Gradle https://gradle.org/.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse only takes care of the compile-time dependencies while generating a .jar

Since your generated .jar can be moved to virtually anywhere, the dependencies must again be present during execution time.

You have two options:

1. Execute your jar with the `-jar` option, while leaving all
   dependencies in the same folder. Since your manifest uses "./" as `classpath`, this means all dependencies must be on the same directory you are executing your jar from. **NOTE** classpath is relative to the directory you are *executing* from, not the directory the file is on.
2. Execute your jar withour the `-jar` option, and specify the `-cp` option to point to the dependencies, and the specify the main class.

`java -cp "<path to your jar>;<path to dependency 1>;<path to dependency 3>[;...]" <your main class>`